# How to open second window from 1st window in pyqt?

Tags: python, window, pyqt

I have 2 forms, `form_1` and `form_2` (in another `class` and `file`), I'll open `form_2` from `form_1` with button,
How to create it in PyQT?

`form_1` code :

```py
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    QtCore.QObject.connect(
        self.bt_form1, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.show_form2())
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
    self.bt_form1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FORM_1", None))

def show_form2(self):
    self.form2 = form2(self) # in here ??????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still pretty new to PyQT but I think you can do it like this -

```
def show_form2(self):
    newDialog = uic.loadUi(r"uifile.ui")
    newDialog.show()
```

or if you've subclassed it, make sure you `import` it if it's in another file and use

```
def show_form2(self):
    newDialog = subDialog.subDialog()
    newDialog.show()
```

edit -
oh and make sure you connect it to the buttons click

```
self.bt_form1.clicked.connect(self.show_form2)
```

Comment: i don't understand about SubDiaolog in 
 def show_form2(self):
    newDialog = subDialog.subDialog()
    newDialog.show()
what its mean ?

i tried but display a description "object has no attribute 'show"

Comment: the subdialog would be your form2

Comment: i've problem n display "object has no attribute 'show'", why ?

Comment: Are you sure you're inheriting from QDialog in that other form?

Comment: i think no, but i create show from QtGui not in class form2..
like this,,:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: i think if you show us the code for your second dialog, we might be able to help more, as by the sounds of it your second dialog is being set up wrong, and not inheriting from a QDialog as this is where it gets the show function from i think

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__( ... )

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.bt_form1,     QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.show_form2())
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.bt_form1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FORM_1", None))

    def show_form2(self):
        self.form2 = Form2(self)
        self.form2.show()
```

Your Form2 code should resemble this:

```
class Form2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None) .... 

    # do whatever #
```

Comment: I've tried but it, but error and appear 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'show', are you have understand about this problem ?

Comment: We really can't help without seeing the other form's code. `QDialog()` and `QMainWindow()` classes definitely do have `.show()` method. Also, try it without passing the `parent` attribute.